# React Native Context Content is keep Coming Back

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-reducer, use-context, react-usememo

I want to clear user and do logout in React Native using `useContext`, `useReducer`, and `useMemo`.

My App (AuthContext) has Users Screen (UserContext) in it.

UserContext has `clearUsers()` within `useMemo`

AuthContext has `logout()` within `useMemo`

UserContext's content is cleared if I do:

```
clearUsers();
```

But when I add logout after or before clearUsers, the userContext content is keep coming back after relogin.

```
clearUsers();
logout();
```

Anyone experienced this? Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that circular import reference casued this. After put context as top reference fixed this issue.